# New driver code added , but not being picked up for compile

Tags: drivers

I have developed a Linux device driver. As of now I am compiling it on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with cross-compiler for arm , but the new Linux device driver NOT being picked up for compilation.

Below are steps :

1. created `chardevdriver.c`  file  and stored  in `~/linux/drivers/misc`
2. in `~/linux/drivers/misc` , added Kconfig file :

   ```
   config CHAR_DEV_DRIV
   tristate  "char device driver"
   depends on ARM
   default  y  if  ARM
   help
     Say Y for Kernel implementation of char device driver
   ```
3. in `~/linux/drivers/misc` , added Makefile file :

   ```
   obj-$(CHAR_DEV_DRIV)            += chardevdriver.o
   ```
4. re-generate  `~/linux/.config` file to include new driver :

   ```
   CONFIG_CHAR_DEV_DRIV=m
   ```
5. re-compile as follows :

   ```
   CHK     include/config/kernel.release
     CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
     CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
   make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
     CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
     CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
     CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
     CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
     Building modules, stage 2.
     MODPOST 257 modules
   ```

But my new code in `chardevdriver.c` is NOT being picked up for compilation.

Any Ideas?